# How to run tearDown and setUp in conftest.py

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pytest, fixtures

I need help with my pytest/selenium code.

I have the following code in my *conftest.py* file.

```
import pytest
from base.webdriverfactory import WebDriverFactory
from pages.login_page import LoginPage

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def oneTimesetUp(request, browser):
   print("Running one time setUp")
   wdf = WebDriverFactory(browser)
   driver = wdf.getWebDriverInstance()
   lp = LoginPage(driver)
   lp.login("haykpo", "Aaaa4321")

   if request.cls is not None:
       request.cls.driver = driver
   yield driver
   lp.log_out_from_wp_page()
   driver.quit()
   print("Running one time tearDown")
```

And here is my test file where I use this fixture

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimesetUp", "tearDown")
class TestPublishWithOfflinewAsset:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def objectSetup(self, oneTimesetUp):
        self.pub = TestPublishofflineWOMedia(self.driver)

    def test_publish_with_off_w_media(self):
        self.pub.select_project('Test cases - Avallain')
        self.pub.check_lo_plays_normally(15292)
```

I know that whatever comes after yield is meant to be code as tearDown. So I have written these 2 lines in order to log out from the app and quit the browser at the end of the test execution.

```
lp.log_out_from_wp_page()
driver.quit()
```

However, the problem is that the log out part (not the quit one interestingly) is always being executed after few steps when my test starts and when browser focus switch  to iframe during test execution (or may be this is just a coincidence am not sure if iframe is guilty here). How can I compose my code to run my teardown log out or whatever I want after yield as intended but not during test execution?

For more details here is the detailed files with code. 
The below one is my Login page

```
from base.basepage import BasePage

class LoginPage(BasePage):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        self.driver = driver

    ### Locators ###
    _name_field = "form1:Name"
    _password_field = "form1:Password"
    _login_button = "form1:loginButton"
    _work_packages = "wpButton"
    _user_logout_dropdown_button = 'rolebutton_button'
    _logout_button = 'blogout'


    def log_out_from_wp_page(self):
        self.elementClick(locator=self._user_logout_dropdown_button)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.elementClick(locator=self._logout_button)
```

And below one is webdriver factory

```
class WebDriverFactory:

    def __init__(self, browser):
        self.browser = browser

    def getWebDriverInstance(self):
        """
       Get WebDriver Instance based on the browser configuration

        Returns:
            'WebDriver Instance'
        """
        global driver
        baseURL = "https://example.com"
        if self.browser == "iexplorer":
            # Set ie driver
            driver = webdriver.Ie()
        elif self.browser == "firefox":
            driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        elif self.browser == "chrome":
            # Set chrome driver
            driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            #driver.set_window_size(1440, 900)
        else:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        # Setting Driver Implicit Time out for An Element
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        # Maximize the windows
        driver.maximize_window()
        # Loading browser with App URL
        driver.get(baseURL)
        return driver
```

The below one is BasePsge

```
class BasePage(SeleniumDriver):

   def __init__(self, driver):

        super(BasePage, self).__init__(driver)
        self.driver = driver
```

Comment: This is certainly interesting. Have you tried scoping it to `session` instead of `class`? Otherwise try this approach here https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html#class-level-setup-teardown

Comment: Need to see what log_out_from_wp_page() , with out that its not easy to answer your question.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted - why do you suspect the fixture teardown is issue? Add a line `if True: raise Exception()` to `log_out_from_wp_page` and check where the error trace comes from.

Comment: @techouse Scoping session or module instead of class does not work at all. Will look at the docs.

Comment: @stacktome here is the code                                                                                                                          
     `def log_out_from_wp_page(self):   
                               
        self.elementClick(locator=self._user_logout_dropdown_button)     
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.elementClick(locator=self._logout_button)`

Comment: @hoefling I suspect that as my log_out function contains driver and in my setUp I am yielding driver, that is the reason why log_out is being executed. Anyway the problem is that I consider everything after yield as teardown which should not be executed before test is finished. So my goal is to somehow define teardown with my desired code.

Comment: You are correct, fixture code after `yield` will execute after the test code finishes, this is why I don't think it's an issue and the logout is executed from somewhere else. You can of course use `request.addfinalizer` for teardown instead of yielding, but I don't see why yielding shouldn't work. Can you add a [mcve]?

Comment: @hoefling I edited my question and added all respective files in order to clarify the overall picture. You see in original question more code.

Comment: Can you also add the `TestPublishofflineWOMedia` class?

Comment: @hoefling it is pretty big file which includes all test page actions and methods. That class inherits from base page. Here is the init constructor of class `TestPublishofflineWOMedia(BasePage):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        self.driver = driver `  However, I believe that the issue here is in pytest fixtures setUp and oneTimesetUp. I think yield is interpreted differently for each of this fixtures but why and how I don`t know. I changed the fixture from oneTimesetUp to setUp and yield worked but it does not work with oneTimesetUp.